# Why do I get ORA-00979 here?

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
SELECT e1.nombreEquipo, p1.idTemporada, COUNT (*)
FROM equipo e1 INNER JOIN partido p1
ON e1.nombreEquipo = p1.nombreLocal OR
    e1.nombreEquipo = p1.nombreVisitante
WHERE p1.golesLocal = p1.golesVisitante
GROUP BY e1.nombreEquipo, p1.idTemporada
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 
(
    SELECT COUNT (*)
    FROM partido p2
    WHERE (e1.nombreEquipo = p2.nombreLocal OR e1.nombreEquipo = p2.nombreVisitante) AND (p1.golesLocal = p2.golesLocal) AND
          (p1.idTemporada = p2.idTemporada)
)
```

I'm trying to use this code for an SQL query, but I get the ORA-00936 error when I try to run the script. I have read on several pages that this error is caused by not putting all the select columns in the group by line, but I think I haven´t missed any of them.

It's the first time I use SQL and don't know very much about it.

Comment: COUNT(\*) also results in a column. Try changing it to either COUNT(e1.nombreEquipo) or COUNT(p1.idTemporada).

Comment: So which is it, ORA-00979 or ORA-00936?

Comment: @luc14n0 I know, but if I put COUNT(*) at the end of the group by line, the console of Eclipse shows the ORA-00934 error

Comment: You can't use p1.golesLocal in the having clause without adding them to the group by clause. Try adding it to the `group by` or use `max(p1.golesLocal)` (or min) to use it in the having clause

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the `HAVING` clause:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) >= (
    SELECT COUNT (*)
    FROM partido p2
    WHERE (e1.nombreEquipo = p2.nombreLocal OR
           e1.nombreEquipo = p2.nombreVisitante
          ) AND (p1.golesLocal = p2.golesLocal) AND
-----------------^
          (p1.idTemporada = p2.idTemporada)   
)
```

The column `p1.golesLocal` is not in the `GROUP BY`, so it cannot be used after the aggregation, unless it is the argument to an aggregation function.

I can't suggest a fix because I don't know the intention of the query.

Comment: I have to show the football teams that have had the maximum number of ties in each football season.

Comment: @alberto . . . I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Explain the problem and provide sample data and desired results.  (This question is about a syntax error; the other question would be about solving your problem.)